# Store blob image on server with python

Tags: django, python-3.x, blob, tinymce-4

I have `img` tags on my page with `blob` src

```
<img src="blob:http%3A//mydoma.in/43b92f51-3f04-4027-b6a4-01c5bcc68b2d" />
```

They are created by pasting (Ctrl+V) with TinyMCE 4 option `paste_data_images: true`.
I want to upload such images to my Python Django server (to store them as static and some processing, e.g. applying watermarks). But the problem is I don't know how to get blob object, if I only have an url `blob:http%3A//mydoma.in/43b92f51-3f04-4027-b6a4-01c5bcc68b2d`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like I don't need this because "blob://" automatically replaced with base64 data when POSTing to server, so I only need to parse base64 on server and write decoded bytes to disk, and replace src in img tag to uploaded file url.

I use python3 Django, and here is my code, maybe it will be useful for somebody:

```
# post.content here is uploaded content of text field
post.content = re.sub(
    r'<img (class=".*?" )?src="data:image/(?P<fmt>.+?);base64,(?P<dat>(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4}){2,}(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}[AEIMQUYcgkosw048]=|[A-Za-z0-9+/][AQgw]==))".*?>',
    lambda x: proc_blob(post, x), post.content)

def proc_blob(post, mo):
    data = mo.group('dat')
    fmt = mo.group('fmt')
    fname = "{}_{}.{}".format(post.id, str(time.time()).replace('.', '_'), fmt)
    full_name = os.path.join(IMAGES_ROOT, fname)
    fh = open(full_name, "wb")
    fh.write(base64.b64decode(data))
    fh.close()

    # you can apply a watermark here        

    # Optionally in addition we can store image filename in database (for example to remeber what images are related to post)
    im = app.models.Image(post=post, filename=fname)
    im.save()

    return '<img src="/images/{}" class="img-responsive" />'.format(fname)
```